# How to give a typescript type for hobbies in the below mentioned scenario?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, typescript-typings

hobbies can get two possible values.

1. an empty array like `[]`.
2. an array of objects like `[{id:0, hobby:'cooking'},{id:1, hobby:'sports'}]`.

How to write the type of **hobbies** variable where it can get two possible values like mentioned above.

Comment: hobbies is the variable which can get two values like [] or [{id: 0, hobby: 'cooking'}].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need **one type** for this case. It will cover **both** the empty and the full array cases.

```
interface Hobby {
  id: number;
  hobby: string;
}

let emptyArray: Hobby[] = [];
let fullArray: Hobby[] = [{id: 0, hobby: 'cooking'}];
```

Comment: Yeah this is how I would have approached it. Helps reinforce OOP concepts too. If he wants to make it a full blown class with functions, that may be helpful as well.

Comment: 'fullArray' variable will get both the values 1) [] and 2) [{id: 0, hobby: 'cooking'}]. In this case how to handle it?

Comment: Yes. Both 1) and 2) are array of the same type, it doesn't matter if they are empty or full. The only condition here, is if they are full, they need to have element of the form `{id: 0, hobby: 'cooking'}`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

Create a class called Hobby and give it properties:

```
export default class Hobby { id: number, hobby: string }
```

Then in the component where you define hobbies you can import the new class Hobby and create a property like

```
hobbies: Hobby[]
```

Hope this helps!